# Pandas read csv without header (which might be there)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to read a `.csv` file in chunks (python-engine) and skip the header (or any lines starting with a comment character). It is not known *a priori* if the file has a header or not, so it is not possible to just skip the first line, since it might already be a data row.

Setting `header=None` does solve the problem. If I invoke `get_chunk` and want the row values, I still get the header/or comment line.

Desired output would be just the same like `numpy.loadtxt()`

The code below demonstrates what's going on:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.parsers import TextFileReader
fn = '/tmp/test.csv'
np.savetxt(fn, np.arange(300).reshape(100,3), header="makes no sense")
print np.loadtxt(fn).shape # output (100,3)

reader = TextFileReader(fn, chunksize=10, header=None)
reader.get_chunk().values

# output
array([['#', 'makes', 'no', 'sense'],
       ['0.000000000000000000e+00', '1.000000000000000000e+00',
        '2.000000000000000000e+00', None],
       ['3.000000000000000000e+00', '4.000000000000000000e+00',
        '5.000000000000000000e+00', None],
       ['6.000000000000000000e+00', '7.000000000000000000e+00',
        '8.000000000000000000e+00', None],
       ['9.000000000000000000e+00', '1.000000000000000000e+01',
        '1.100000000000000000e+01', None],
       ['1.200000000000000000e+01', '1.300000000000000000e+01',
        '1.400000000000000000e+01', None],
       ['1.500000000000000000e+01', '1.600000000000000000e+01',
        '1.700000000000000000e+01', None],
       ['1.800000000000000000e+01', '1.900000000000000000e+01',
        '2.000000000000000000e+01', None],
       ['2.100000000000000000e+01', '2.200000000000000000e+01',
        '2.300000000000000000e+01', None],
       ['2.400000000000000000e+01', '2.500000000000000000e+01',
        '2.600000000000000000e+01', None]], dtype=object)
```

If I specify the comment char via

```
   reader = TextFileReader(fn, chunksize=10, header=None, comment='#')
```

I get an exception:

```
In [99]: reader = pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader('/tmp/test.csv', chunksize=10, header=None, index_col=False, comment="#")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-64b1c0bce4ef> in <module>()
----> 1 reader = pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader('/tmp/test.csv', chunksize=10, header=None, index_col=False, comment="#")

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    560             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    561 
--> 562         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    563 
    564     def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
    703             elif engine == 'python-fwf':
    704                 klass = FixedWidthFieldParser
--> 705             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
    706 
    707     def _failover_to_python(self):

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   1400         # Set self.data to something that can read lines.
   1401         if hasattr(f, 'readline'):
-> 1402             self._make_reader(f)
   1403         else:
   1404             self.data = f

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _make_reader(self, f)
   1505                 self.pos += 1
   1506                 self.line_pos += 1
-> 1507                 sniffed = csv.Sniffer().sniff(line)
   1508                 dia.delimiter = sniffed.delimiter
   1509                 if self.encoding is not None:

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/csv.pyc in sniff(self, sample, delimiters)
    180 
    181         quotechar, doublequote, delimiter, skipinitialspace = \
--> 182                    self._guess_quote_and_delimiter(sample, delimiters)
    183         if not delimiter:
    184             delimiter, skipinitialspace = self._guess_delimiter(sample,

/home/marscher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/csv.pyc in _guess_quote_and_delimiter(self, data, delimiters)
    221                       '(?:^|\n)(?P<quote>["\']).*?(?P=quote)(?:$|\n)'):                            #  ".*?" (no delim, no space)
    222             regexp = re.compile(restr, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
--> 223             matches = regexp.findall(data)
    224             if matches:
    225                 break

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

**Edit** this error is caused by not wrapping comment in a list.

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to skip comment lines? there is a `comment` param for `read_csv`, your question is unclear what does your csv look like and what are you trying to resolve?

Comment: the csv if written with numpy (the code example I gave) :

Comment: # makes no sense
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00

Comment: Well this worked fine for me: `df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\np.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, comment='#')`

Comment: if I pass the comment wrapped in a list, I do not get the TypeError anymore, but still the outcome is not the expected one.

Comment: Did you try my code? Also why use a TextFileReader when the csv reader works fine?

Comment: because I need the data in chunks and the docs state that read_csv will return an instance of that class, if chunksize is passed as an argument.

Comment: You've still not told me whether my code worked or not? Have you tried passing `sep='\s+'`?

Comment: yes. Now It contains a fourth column filled with nan and all numbers are strings instead of floats

Comment: Sorry I don't get that result I get 3 columns all are floats

Comment: `read_csv` takes a `chunksize` arg, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @deinonychusaur See the code of the question, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is super old, and I never figured out what's going on with your comment error (and your clarification of the problem didn't fix it for me, but I think it has something to do with calling a class rather than a function), but several modifications provide the output I think you're looking for.

First, if you tell the reader there is no header, it will interpret any header lines as data, determining both the shape and type of data read in (e.g., string format for numbers). It can infer whether there is a header, to not screw up the shape, leaving comments as a separate issue.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.parsers import TextFileReader
fn = '/tmp/test.csv'
np.savetxt(fn, np.arange(300).reshape(100,3), header="makes no sense")
np.loadtxt(fn).shape # output (100,3)

reader = TextFileReader(fn, chunksize=10, header='infer')
reader.get_chunk().values

#output, just inferring headers
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,  nan],
   [  3.,   4.,   5.,  nan],
   [  6.,   7.,   8.,  nan],
   [  9.,  10.,  11.,  nan],
   [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  nan],
   [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  nan],
   [ 18.,  19.,  20.,  nan],
   [ 21.,  22.,  23.,  nan],
   [ 24.,  25.,  26.,  nan],
   [ 27.,  28.,  29.,  nan]])
```

The nan comes from interpreting the commented line as a header (which it is, though also commented out), which has four parts.

You can get rid of the comment mark on the header by changing how you save the text.

```
np.savetxt(fn, np.arange(300).reshape(100,3), header="makes no      sense",comments=None)
reader = TextFileReader(fn, chunksize=10, header='infer')
reader.get_chunk().values
#output, without true header commented out
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
   [  3.,   4.,   5.],
   [  6.,   7.,   8.],
   [  9.,  10.,  11.],
   [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
   [ 15.,  16.,  17.],
   [ 18.,  19.,  20.],
   [ 21.,  22.,  23.],
   [ 24.,  25.,  26.],
   [ 27.,  28.,  29.]])
```

This eliminates the problem with the commented out header, but doesn't help to infer the correct shape, or if you have real comments you also want to ignore.

If you want to infer whether there is a header, and also ignore any commented lines, I can only figure out how to do that by calling a function.

```
import pandas
np.savetxt(fn, np.arange(300).reshape(100,3), header="makes no sense")
reader = pandas.read_csv(fn,chunksize=10,header='infer',comment="#")
reader.get_chunk().values
#output, treating the header as a comment, so shape is decided by first data line
array([[ '3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00'],
   [ '6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00'],
   [ '9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+01 1.100000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.200000000000000000e+01 1.300000000000000000e+01 1.400000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.500000000000000000e+01 1.600000000000000000e+01 1.700000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.800000000000000000e+01 1.900000000000000000e+01 2.000000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.100000000000000000e+01 2.200000000000000000e+01 2.300000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.400000000000000000e+01 2.500000000000000000e+01 2.600000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.700000000000000000e+01 2.800000000000000000e+01 2.900000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '3.000000000000000000e+01 3.100000000000000000e+01 3.200000000000000000e+01']], dtype=object)

#Or, without the commented out header
np.savetxt(fn, np.arange(300).reshape(100,3), header="makes no sense",comments='')
reader = pandas.read_csv(fn,chunksize=10,header='infer',comment="#")
reader.get_chunk().values
#output, treating the header as a header to determine shape, but comments would also be ignored
array([[ '0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00'],
   [ '3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00'],
   [ '6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00'],
   [ '9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+01 1.100000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.200000000000000000e+01 1.300000000000000000e+01 1.400000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.500000000000000000e+01 1.600000000000000000e+01 1.700000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '1.800000000000000000e+01 1.900000000000000000e+01 2.000000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.100000000000000000e+01 2.200000000000000000e+01 2.300000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.400000000000000000e+01 2.500000000000000000e+01 2.600000000000000000e+01'],
   [ '2.700000000000000000e+01 2.800000000000000000e+01 2.900000000000000000e+01']], dtype=object)
```