# How to convert an excel file data into numpy array using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, keras

I am really new in keras library and also Python. I am trying to import an excel file using pandas and convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` using `as_matrix()` function of pandas. But it seams to read my file wrong. Like I have a 90x1049 data set in Excel file. But when i am trying to convert it into numpy array it reads my data as 89x1049. I am using the following code, which is not working:

```
training_data_x = pd.read_excel("/home/workstation/ANN/new_input.xlsx")
X_train = training_data_x.as_matrix()
```

Comment: I'm guessing your excel file has no header row as the first row. Could you include a sample of the resulting `pandas.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what happens is that your Excel file has no header row and so `pandas.read_excel` consumes your first data row as such.

I tried creating an xlsx containing

```
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
4   5   6
5   6   7
6   7   8
7   8   9
8   9   10
9   10  11
10  11  12
```

Reading that resulted in

```
In [3]: df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx')

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    1   2   3
0   2   3   4
1   3   4   5
2   4   5   6
3   5   6   7
4   6   7   8
5   7   8   9
6   8   9  10
7   9  10  11
8  10  11  12
```

As can be seen, the first data row has been used as labels for columns.

To avoid consuming the first data row as headers, pass `header=None` to `read_excel`. Interestingly the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) did not mention this usage before, but has been fixed since:

> **header** : *int, list of ints, default 0*
>
> Row (0-indexed) to use for the column labels of the parsed DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed those row positions will be combined into a `MultiIndex`. Use None if there are no headers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no header, try the following:

```
training_data = pd.read_excel("/home/workstation/ANN/new_input.xlsx", header=None)

X_train = training_data_x.as_matrix()
```

See also answers from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539742/pandas-read-csv-without-header-which-might-be-there).

Comment: When using `.as_matrix` the following warning appears: FutureWarning: Method `.as_matrix` will be removed in a future version. Use `.values` instead. So using `.values` is probably a better option now